# Apply Policy to Resource Controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, authorization, crud

I have a `CRUD` Resource defined via `Route::resource('User', 'UserController')`.

Since it is possible to generate `CRUD` Gates and Policies, is there a way to apply such a Gate / Policy, so that the corresponding gate / policy is applied to a specific route?

I think that would be an elegant way, since my polices would match my routes. I'm looking for a method like *applyPolicy* or something simliar:

`Route::resource('User', 'UserController')->applyPolicy()`

Otherwise I would have to add each policy to each action, which doesn't seem so elegant.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at the `authorizeResource(Model::class)` method.

An example would be in your controller's constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->authorizeResource(Task::class);
}
```